# Why is the min state getting updated 2 times instead of only once?

Tags: reactjs

Why is the min state getting updated in the multiples of two instead of just updating by one after every 59 seconds? How do I fix it?

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

export const Timer = () => {
  const [second, setSecond] = useState(0);
  const [min, setMin] = useState(0);
  const watch = useRef(null);

  const startTimer = () => {
    watch.current = setInterval(() => {
      setSecond((value) => {
        if (value === 59) {
          setSecond(0);
          setMin((v) => v + 1);
        }

        return value + 1;
      });
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        {min}:{second}{" "}
      </h1>
      <button onClick={startTimer}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={() => clearInterval(watch.current)}>Pause</button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setSecond(0);
          return clearInterval(watch.current);
        }}
      >
        Reset
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the component as a whole. I am new to react so please help.

Comment: This works fine for me– did you accidentally click "Start" multiple times?

Comment: Do you have `<StrictMode>` enabled? I see doubling in codesandbox with strictmode on. (But i will say that calling `setSecond` inside another `setSecond` call seems like trouble.)